# Make Color of an Element Pulse Continuously With Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make the color of a button pulse from its current color, say, #ed8c55, to pure white and back to the original color with the entire cycle taking about 2-3 seconds. How could I do that?

In particular, I see that there are a couple of problems here. One is to make the timer and attach some variable's increment to the value of the color. The second problem is the actual color itself. How would one go about continuously changing a hex color towards white and back using a loop of some sort?

I have the following timer implemented that counts seconds. I could easily modify it to count milliseconds or something like that.

```
var mytimeout = null; // the current timeoutID
    $scope.counter = 0;

    // actual timer method, counts up every second
        $scope.onTimeout = function() {

        $scope.counter++;
        mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
    };
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I know you want an animation via AngularJS but I dont think thats the right tool for the job as its easily achieved via CSS alone. I'd really advise you to do it like so;

EDIT ------------------

After your comments of dynamically adding a background colour that will then pulse the best way is to inline style the colour via angular and css keyframe the animation.

CSS --

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  25% { background-color: #FFF; }  
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  25% { background-color: #FFF; }  
}

@-o-keyframes pulse {
  25% { background-color: #FFF; }
}

@keyframes pulse { 
  25% { background-color: #FFF; } // changed to 25% to stop the sudden change to white
}

.element {
    transition: background-color 3s;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 3s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation:    pulse 3s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation:      pulse 3s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation:         pulse 3s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
  }
```

HTML -

```
<div style="background-color: #ed8c55;" class="element"></div>
```

[View my codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKKroo)

/ EDIT ------------------

OG Answer ---

```
  @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
    50% { background-color: #FFF; }
    100% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
    50% { background-color: #FFF; }
    100% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
  }

  @-o-keyframes pulse {
    0% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
    50% { background-color: #FFF; }
    100% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
  }

  @keyframes pulse {
    0% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
    50% { background-color: #FFF; }
    100% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
  }

  .element {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ed8c55;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 3s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation:    pulse 3s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation:      pulse 3s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation:         pulse 3s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
  }
```

And that will continuously loop between the two colours.

[You can view my code pen on it here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzKxZW)

Comment: Yes, Angular is not mandatory! Thanks, I am reading your answer now!

Comment: A question: what if I do not want to hard-code the color into CSS. That is, in my app the color needed is pulled from database at runtime. Could I somehow pass it into CSS?

Comment: So check my edit. If you know what colours you would want it changed to you could update a class on `.element`.

Comment: You are phenomenally proficient with these things! Much appreciated!

Comment: @MadPhysicist haha thanks! Hey if my answers the right one for you could you mark it as correct?

Comment: Will do. I am working on trying them out now. Is this strictly CSS stuff? What should I look up to learn more about the things you used?

Comment: @MadPhysicist ah sure thing no problem. Yeah its all CSS3. You can learn more about css from here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114574/discussion-between-madphysicist-and-mark).

Comment: Hey, mate, I am still working on this and wondering if there is a way to pack all of those @keyframes into a single CSS class and still have it work? I am really having a difficult time finding an Angular method that would allow for a nice injection of values into separate CSS classes. Now, it has no problems injecting values into single CSS keys for styling of an element, but that is not what I need.

Comment: Hey man, I got you. Check out my edit. This allows you to dynamically change the inline-style to the colour which then pulses that colour :)

Comment: to all who ended up here, I would like to add a new solution that works even in Angular 13: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63101535/change-css-variables-dynamically-in-angular