# Change css variables dynamically in angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, css-variables

In my angular project, I have some css variables defined in top level **styles.scss** file like this. I use these variable at many places to keep the whole theme consistent.

```
:root {
  --theme-color-1: #f7f7f7;
  --theme-color-2: #ec4d3b;
  --theme-color-3: #ffc107;
  --theme-color-4: #686250;

  --font-weight: 300
}
```

How can I update values of these variables dynamically from **app.component.ts** ? And What is the **clean way** to do this in angular ?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66244720/1974681

Comment: The solution detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68089667/9649530 works for me. Similar to some of the following answers, but do the job in the HTML.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can update them using

```
 document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--theme-color-1', '#fff');
```

If u want to update many values, then create a object

```
 this.styles = [
      { name: 'primary-dark-5', value: "#111" },
      { name: 'primary-dark-7_5', value: "#fff" },
    ];

 this.styles.forEach(data => {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${data.name}`, data.value);
 });
```

The main thing here is `document.documentElement.style.setProperty`. This line allows you to access the root element (HTML tag) and assigns/overrides the style values.

Note that the names of the variables should match at both places(css and js files)

---

if you don't want to use document API, then you can use inline styles on HTML tag directly

```
    const styleObject = {};

    this.styles.forEach(data => {
      styleObject[`--${data.name}`] = data.value;
    });
```

Then In your template file using ngStyle [(https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

> Set a collection of style values using an expression that returns
> key-value pairs.
>
> ```
> <some-element [ngStyle]="objExp">...</some-element>
> ```

```
<html [ngStyle]="styleObject" >...</html>  //not sure about quotes syntax
```

---

Above methods do the same thing, "Update root element values" but in a different way.

When you used `:root`, the styles automatically got attached to HTML tag

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to use DOM api straightly. That's why i asked the second question regarding the clean/angular way.

Comment: @abhaytripathi, do you have access to html tag?I mean can you add attributes to HTML tag?

Comment: ngStyle might help, I will try some permutation and combinations of your suggestion.

Comment: Than i let you know in this regard.

Answer (score 12):

Starting with Angular v9 you can use the style binding to change a value of a custom property

```
<app-component-name [style.--theme-color-1]="'#CCC'"></app-component-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some examples add variables directly to html tag and it seem in the element source as a long list. I hope this helps to you,

```js
class AppComponent {
  private variables=['--my-var: 123;', '--my-second-var: 345;'];

  private addAsLink(): void {
    const cssVariables = `:root{ ${this.variables.join('')}};
    const blob = new Blob([cssVariables]);
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const cssElement = document.createElement('link');
    cssElement.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    cssElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    cssElement.setAttribute('href', url);
    document.head.appendChild(cssElement);
  }
}
```