How to increase and decrease font size in all html pages of an angular application
I am creating a web application in angular and I need to add floating menu which permits to increase and decrease font size for people who have vision problem.
Can someone help me how to do that.
Thanks folks
I'am tryong FontService and data- attributes but it doesnt work

This is super easy to do with just CSS if you define your font sizes in rem and then change the font-size of the <body>... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

You can also just * { font-size: ... !important; } in your global styles (styles.css by default). Setting the style to a CSS variable will let you edit the value from your .ts files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63101535/change-css-variables-dynamically-in-angular

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I would do this by overriding a CSS variable using renderer2:
// styles.scss

:host {
  --app-font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  font-size: var(--app-font-size);
}

The updateFontSize method in the example below takes an explicit size argument, but you could do a mathematical increment/decrement calculation instead.
// font-size.component.ts

export class FontSizeComponent {
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  updateFontSize(size: string) {
    this.renderer.setProperty(
      document.documentElement,
      'style',
      `--app-font-size: ${size}`
    );
  }
}

<!-- font-size.component.html -->

<button (click)="updateFontSize('18px')">+ Font Size</button>
<button (click)="updateFontSize('14px')">- Font Size</button>

